Show that a subspace topology coincides with another subspace topology
The question is as follows: Given subsets $A \subseteq B$ of a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, with $A \neq \emptyset$, let $\mathcal{T}_A, \mathcal{T}_B$ be the subspace topologies on $A, B$ induced by $\mathcal{T}$. Prove that $\mathcal{T}_A$ coincides with the topology on $A$ induced by $\mathcal{T}_B$.
My solution is as follows: Let the subspace topology on $A$ induced by $\mathcal{T}_B$ be denoted as $\mathcal{T}_{B|A}$. Then we have: $\mathcal{T}_{B|A} = \{A \cap U : U \in \mathcal{T}_{B}\} = \{A \cap (B \cap U) : U \in \mathcal{T}\} = \{(A \cap B) \cap U : U \in \mathcal{T}\} = \{A \cap U : U \in \mathcal{T}\} = \mathcal{T}_A$ Hence, $\mathcal{T}_{B|A}$ coincides with  $\mathcal{T}_{A}$.
The solution I came across actually uses double inclusion to show that both topologies are equal, which makes sense. However, I feel like my proof is shorter, and better were it to be correct. Is my proof correct? Any feedback is appreaciated!

Seems right to me. (I think your proof is just a shorter version of double inclusion check.)

Agreed. For future readers, you might consider self-answering, perhaps adding the detail of why $(A\cap B)\cap U=A\cap U$.
